# If statement in batch script isn't working?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I have a batch script which when given the input "edit", should then echo "hello" as a sort of debug and open the batch scripts file in notepad.  However for some inexplicable reason the script will not respond to the if statement no matter what.  How do I get it to respond to the "edit" input?

```
REM @ECHO OFF
cd/
cd projects\py_test
ECHO Use this batch script to lauch Python modules living in "C:\Projects\py_test\" ONLY.
ECHO.
SET /P name="Type file name with file extension .py to start or type EDIT to edit this .bat: "
REM @ECHO OFF
cmd /k IF %name%==edit GOTO EDIT
REM IF EXIST %name% py %name%
REM IF NOT EXIST %name% echo  [101mERROR: The requested file could not be found.  Make sure the file exists in "C:\Projects\py_test\" and that the filename includes the ".py" extension.[0m 
@ECHO OFF
:EDIT
ECHO HELLO
notepad projects-py_test-dot_start.bat`
```

Comment: In my opinion the entire script is pointless, but was I to use such a thing, I think I'd create a `.py` script named `edit.py`. That way the user just enters the name and it is run from python; _it'll make the process more understandable and straight forward, and would mean the the end user didn't needlessly have to append `.py` to their entry, as it would be a valid suffix on every entry_.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, why all the `REM @ECHO OFF`s? It looks ugly, especially when they are all caps.

Then, you want to run `cmd /k` for an if statement for no real reason? With the variable name you need to preferbly enclose the if statement variables in double quotes to eliminate possible whitespace:

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\projects\py_test"
echo Use this batch script to lauch Python modules living in "C:\Projects\py_test\" ONLY.
echo/
set /p name="Type file name with file extension .py to start or type EDIT to edit this .bat: "
if defined name set "name=%name:"=%"
if /i "%name%"=="edit" goto edit
goto :EOF
:edit
echo hello
notepad echo "%~f0"
```

but by guessing that you simply want to launch a python script if it exists, else edit itself, then I would instead do this version without the labels. It simply checks if the name typed exists (hoping the user typed the full script with extension) else, we add the extension test in case the user typed only the name and not extension.:

```
@echo off
cd /d "C:\projects\py_test"
echo Use this batch script to lauch Python modules living in "C:\Projects\py_test\" ONLY.
echo/
set /p name="Type file name with file extension .py to start or type EDIT to edit this .bat: "
 if defined name set "name=%name:"=%"
 if /i "%name%"=="edit" notepad "%~f0"
 if exist "%name%" (
             python "%name%"
    ) else (
            if exist "%name%.py" (
                      python "%name%.py"
       ) else (
             echo "%name%" does not exist
     )
  )
```

Comment: Gerhard, as the file to edit is the batch file itself, I would suggest that you utilise the `%0` option instead of `projects-py_test-dot_start.bat`. This would mean that regardless of any future renaming of the file, it would still be found for editing.

Comment: @Compo Thanks, will add it, I however suspect the OP wants that feature to edit a file if it does not exist (i.e a python file), but yes, it is not specified anyway, thanks for good point!

Comment: Gerhard, I would not advocate using `"%~dpf0"` which makes little sense, instead going for just `%0`, _which should auto enclose itself with doublequotes_. However if it makes you feel safer, perhaps `"%~f0"` or `"%~dpnx0"` as alternatives.

Comment: @Compo the reason is because we do a `cd` earlier in the batch, so just doing `%0` would try and open the file inside the cd'd dir, but `%~f0` is better yes.

Comment: @Gerhard, just because you used `CD` earlier shouldn't necessarily matter, try it! 1. `@CD /D E:\DATA`, 2. `@Echo([%0]`, 3. `@Pause`. The output will be something along these lines, `["C:\Users\Gerhard\Desktop\test.cmd"]`, i.e. the full path enclosed within doublequotes.

Comment: Gerhard, I stated in my previous comment, the usage of CD didn't necessarily matter, _I didn't say never_! The method of invoking the script can make a difference, _(double click my previous example)_, it should work fine. Using [an example similar to yours](https://i.imgur.com/75QEL7S.png) can you see what I mean? In this case, I find it difficult to believe that an end user would want to either CD to a directory and type in the name of a batch file, or type in a full path to a batch file, to then be asked for the full name and extension of a python file in order to run that python file.

Comment: @Compo yes, hence why I use `%~f0` instead :) But yes, I sometimes do not even question why people do what they do, when there are many better methods to do things, I just give what they ask. At times I do, at times I don't

Comment: I know what you mean, but assumption would be that the batch script is more than likely a simple way for Kelsey to save the end user from having to type in full paths or navigate to directories. _I'd expect that the batch script does all of that for them and sets up any necessary environment before invoking their 'module'_. If the end user is typing full paths or navigating to directories in the command prompt themselves, it would be a pointless exercise. The script could be run from a shortcut though, which could theoretically change the method of invoking, so I agree with using `%~f0`.

Comment: @compo. Cool. Agreed.